# How to get the left location of a cell in a TableLayoutPanel in pixels on form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, cell, tablelayoutpanel

How can i get the **left location** of a cell in a `TableLayoutPanel` in pixels on form in C# WinForms .Net v2.0?

**Edit:** I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725721/get-height-and-width-of-tablelayoutpanel-cell-in-windows-forms) but it only has `Width` and `Height`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the `Width`s of every cell to get the `Left` of a specific cell using this code:

```
int left = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < theCellIndex; i++)
  left += tableLayoutPanel1.GetColumnWidths()[i];
```