# Capture image of specific area of a TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, tablelayoutpanel, image-capture

I have a Project that uses a `TableLayoutPanel` control.
I want capture image of specific area of that `TableLayoutPanel`.
I have an image (which is captured) width and height info. I also have start-end cell indexes info, I succeeded to capture but the area that captured is wrong.

[image]

This is my code:

```
private void getImage()
{
    int totalWidth = 250 // image width size;
    int totalHeight = 200 // image height size;

    int LeftBottomCellColumnIndex = 3
    int LeftBottomCellRowIndex = 4

    int LeftTopCellColumnIndex = 3
    int LeftBottomCellRowIndex = 2 // I also have all cells index info

    Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(totalWidth, totalHeight);
    tableLayoutPanel2.DrawToBitmap(bm, new Rectangle(0, 0, totalWidth, totalHeight)); // 0,0 problem is here. I do not know what I have to put there

    string path = @"C:\Users\prdn5\TestDrawToBitmap.bmp";
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
    bm.Save(fs, ImageFormat.Bmp);
    fs.Flush();
    fs.Close();
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25261036/how-to-get-the-left-location-of-a-cell-in-a-tablelayoutpanel-in-pixels-on-form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TableLayoutPanel, for some reason, doesn't expose the Cells bounds directly, through a Property or Method. But of course it calculates these values for internal use, since it needs to paint the borders of its Cells.

Its [OnPaintBackground](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TableLayoutPanel.cs,392) method is responsible for this.
When the Control needs to repaint itself, the Cells bounds are recalculated and, for each Cell, the Control raises the [CellPaint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.cellpaint) event. Its [TableLayoutCellPaintEventArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutcellpainteventargs) argument returns both the current Cell's bounds and Column/Row coordinates.
Since this event is raised each time the TableLayoutPanel is modified/resized, we can use the `CellPaint` event handler to store these references.

Here, I'm using a `Dictionary<TableLayoutPanelCellPosition, Rectangle>` to store the coordinates of each Cell and map it to its bounds.

The [Layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.layout) event handler sets a boolean Field that causes the Dictionary to be rebuild only when necessary (because the TableLayoutPanel's Layout has changed).

▶ The Dictionary Key is a [TableLayoutPanelCellPosition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanelcellposition) because it allows a quick and simple equality comparisons. Of course you can use a different type of object, if needed.

▶ Assume the TableLayoutPanel is named **`tlp1`**.

▶ Adding and/or removing Columns/Rows at run-time is not handled. In case it's needed, re-define the Dictionary in the `Layout` event handler instead of the Form Constructor.

```
public partial class SomeForm : Form
{
    Dictionary<TableLayoutPanelCellPosition, Rectangle> tlpCells = null;
    bool calcCells = false;

    public SomeForm() {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Set the DoubleBuffered property via reflection (if needed)
        var flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
        tlp1.GetType().GetProperty("DoubleBuffered", flags).SetValue(tlp1, true);

        tlpCells = new Dictionary<TableLayoutPanelCellPosition, Rectangle>();
        for (int x = 0; x < tlp1.ColumnCount; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < tlp1.RowCount; y++) {
                tlpCells.Add(new TableLayoutPanelCellPosition(x, y), Rectangle.Empty);
            }
        }
    }

    private void tlp1_Layout(object sender, LayoutEventArgs e) => calcCells = true;

    private void tlp1_CellPaint(object sender, TableLayoutCellPaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (calcCells) {
            var cellPos = new TableLayoutPanelCellPosition(e.Column, e.Row);
            tlpCells[cellPos] = e.CellBounds;

            if (cellPos.Column == tlp1.ColumnCount - 1 && 
                cellPos .Row == tlp1.RowCount - 1) calcCells = false;
        }
    }
}
```

To get the Cell from the current Mouse position, call **`GetSelectedCell()`**, passing the current Pointer location, relative to the TableLayoutPanel:

```
var cell = GetSelectedCell(tlp1.PointToClient(MousePosition));
// If called from the MouseMove, MouseDown etc handlers, use the MouseEventArgs instead
var cell = GetSelectedCell(e.Location);

// [...]

private TableLayoutPanelCellPosition GetSelectedCell(Point position) 
    => tlpCells.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Value.Contains(position)).Key;
```

Now, to generate a Bitmap from a range of Cells, you just need to specify the starting  (Left, Top) and ending (Right, Bottom) Cells and pass these values references to the **`TlpCellRangeToBitmap()`** method (it could also be used as an extension method).
If the **`includeBorders`** argument is set to `true`, it will include the external borders of the Cells (see the visual example). Add code that checks whether the TableLayoutPanel actually has borders (`BorderStyle` Property).
The Rectangle that includes the range of Cells is returned by **`GetCellRangeBounds()`**: this method is independent and can be used for other purposes.

For example, set the Image property of a PictureBox to the generated Bitmap:

```
var cellStart = new TableLayoutPanelCellPosition(2, 2);
var cellEnd = new TableLayoutPanelCellPosition(3, 5);

somePictureBox.Image?.Dispose();
somePictureBox.Image = TlpCellRangeToBitmap(tlp1, cellStart, cellEnd, false);

// [...]

private Bitmap TlpCellRangeToBitmap(TableLayoutPanel tlp, TableLayoutPanelCellPosition cellStart, TableLayoutPanelCellPosition cellEnd, bool includeBorders)
{
    // The 3rd parameter includes or excludes the external borders
    var selRect = GetCellRangeBounds(cellStart, cellEnd, includeBorders);
    using (var image = new Bitmap(tlp.Width + 1, tlp.Height + 1)) {
        tlp.DrawToBitmap(image, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, tlp.Size));
        return image.Clone(selRect, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    }
}

private Rectangle GetCellRangeBounds(TableLayoutPanelCellPosition start, TableLayoutPanelCellPosition end, bool extBorders)
{
    var cellStart = tlpCells[start];
    var cellEnd = tlpCells[end];
    if (extBorders) {
        cellStart.Location = new Point(cellStart.X - 1, cellStart.Y - 1);
        cellEnd.Size = new Size(cellEnd.Width + 2, cellEnd.Height + 2);
    }
    return new Rectangle(cellStart.Location, new Size(cellEnd.Right - cellStart.X, cellEnd.Bottom - cellStart.Y));
}
```

---

This is how it works:

[image: TableLayoutPanel Cell Ranges to Bitmap]

Comment: First of all  thank you so much for your effort and time. The information you gave is very important to me like a lesson. In addition it made me understand the process as well. I tried your codes but some times it gives error "out of memory exception".Please see link. [link] (https://ibb.co/gwf6DW8).

Comment: It is my mistake. I found the reason of error. I corrected. Your codes work perfectly. I spent two days to find solution. Thank you so much again. You are life saver:)

Comment: Well, I', glad it was helpful :) The `out of memory` exception is generated if you try to draw to the Bitmap outside its bounds. That's why there's `[...] new Bitmap(tlp.Width + 1, tlp.Height + 1)`: when the external borders are included, the normal rectangular area is 1 pixel wider, so the `Clone()` method may try to create a selection that goes outside the Bitmap bounds when the selection overlaps the TableLayoutPanel's bounds in one or more sides.

Comment: It helped me a lot and I understood the logic of the subject. Many thanx again. I was getting this error when i selected the start cell which column's index is 0. I added condition for this part '= new Point(cellStart.X - 1, cellStart.Y - 1);'. I guess If cell column index 0, cellStart.X will be negative(-1), so this was the reason of error.