# Mouse Move on a cell of my tablelayoutpanel

Tags: c#, cell, mousemove, tablelayoutpanel

I have a problem with my TLP. I would like the cell's color to be changed when the mouse is moving over the cells. I trieed different things but nothing works. Do you have an idea how I could get over this problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLPs are not very nice to work with.

You can use the `TableLayoutCellPaintEventArgs` to learn about a cell while is being painted and convert the cursor's screen position to the relative one with `PointToClient`..

Here is an example, but I'm not sure how well it will work for larger TLPs:

```
private void tableLayoutPanel1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    tableLayoutPanel1.Invalidate();
}

private void tableLayoutPanel1_CellPaint(object sender, TableLayoutCellPaintEventArgs e)
{
    Point pt = tableLayoutPanel1.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);

    using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(e.CellBounds.Contains(pt) ? 
                                             Color.Red : tableLayoutPanel1.BackColor))
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, e.CellBounds);
}
```

This paints the cell the cursor is over and resets when it leaves. If you want to keep the changed color you will need to store it in an 2d-array and use that as the alternative color. The details will depend on just what you want to achieve.

You may also want to study [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725721/get-height-and-width-of-tablelayoutpanel-cell-in-windows-forms?rq=1) to learn more about working with TLPs..

Comment: Thanks for your Help TaW !